# Como seleccionar el segundo y el penutlimo item en php?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Como puedo seleccionar el segundo y penultimo item de una tabla Mysql con php.

yo trate de hacer lo siguiente pero me limita solo a la posicion 12 de 15, y debe mostrarme desde la posicion 2  a la 14 de 15 en total, el segundo y el penultimo item.

la idea es que si se agregan mas posiciones siempre se muestre el penultimo, en caso tal que se agregue una nueva seria 16 y la penultima ya seria 15. y asi con cada registro nuevo.

Mi consulta

```
$query_paradas = "SELECT pos, r_lat, r_lng FROM escolar WHERE 
placa='$placa_id' AND r_ruta='$ruta' AND jornada='$jornada' AND 
estado='activado' AND pos  BETWEEN 2 and 12 ORDER BY pos ASC";
$paradas = mysqli_query( $con, $query_paradas );
```

Muchas gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Marcaste mi respuesta como aceptada, pero no se si funcione en todos tus casos. Que hay en pos? podrias mostrar tus datos? no estoy seguro que esto ande en todos los casos, sobre todo porque el where puede hacer que vengan registros con pos muy distintos.. en ese caso, cual seria el anteultimo? tal vez la solucion con offset sea lo que realmente necesitas

Comment: @gbianchi tu respuesta si puede servir depronto con un `set @id=0; select @id:=@id+1 as pos, r_lat, r_lng 
FROM escolar` pero por php creo que habria que enviarla por un multi query

Comment: @junior tampoco.. si pos es 2,4,5,8 el anteultimo es 5.. no hay manera de calcularlo...

Comment: ¿Necesitas los resultados en dos filas o en una sola fila?

Comment: @gbianchi `@id` es un acomulador

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A ver, veamos tu problema de otra forma...

Vos queres el segundo item, que siempre va a ser `pos = 2`, y tambien el anteultimo, que siempre va a ser `select count(*) - 1 from escolar` ... entonces tu query es mucho mas simple de lo que pensas, ni traer todos, ni traer por partes ni nada...

```
SELECT pos, r_lat, r_lng 
FROM escolar 
WHERE placa='$placa_id' AND r_ruta='$ruta' AND jornada='$jornada' AND 
estado='activado' AND (pos  =2 or pos = (select count(*)-1 from escolar))
```

### Nota:

No estoy seguro si mysql aceptaria la siguiente sintaxis, pero tambien parece una buena idea:

```
SELECT pos, r_lat, r_lng 
FROM escolar 
WHERE placa='$placa_id' AND r_ruta='$ruta' AND jornada='$jornada' AND 
estado='activado' AND pos in (2,(select count(*)-1 from escolar))
```

Comment: no se te olvide que en esta parte `(select count(*)-1 from escolar)` debes colocar todo el where `(select count(*)-1 from escolar WHERE placa='$placa_id' AND r_ruta='$ruta' AND jornada='$jornada' AND 
estado='activado')` sino te va a traer todos los datos de escolar

Comment: totalmente de acuerdo, ahora edito.

Comment: bah.... ahora que lo pienso, puede que asi el query no funcione bien.. dejame volver a revisarlo mentalmente ya que no tengo datos.. porque pueden ser 3 registros, pero el pos del ultimo puede ser 140... @junior

Comment: a lo que te refieres es que se pueden correr los ID cierto

Comment: si.. puede que pos no tenga una correlacion con el count. fijate que le deje un comentario a OP @junior